# regular expression ".*[^a-zA-Z0-9_].*"

Tags: c#, regex

As I am trying to read more about regular expressions in C#, I just want to make sure of my conclusion that I made.
for the following expression ".*[^a-zA-Z0-9_].* ", the  " .* " at the beginning and end are useless, is that right ? because as I understood, that ".*" means zero or more occurrence of any character, but being followed by "[^a-zA-Z0-9_]" which means any character other than any combination of letters and digits case insensitive, makes ".*" useless to be added before and after "[^a-zA-Z0-9_]", is that right ?

Here is the code I am using to check if the expressions matches

```
// Here we call Regex.Match.
Match match = Regex.Match("anytest#", ".*[^a-z A-Z0-9_].*");
//Match match = Regex.Match("anytest#", "[^a-z A-Z0-9_]");

// Here we check the Match instance.
if (match.Success)
    Console.WriteLine("error");
else
    Console.WriteLine("no error");
```

Comment: What do you actually want to match?

Comment: I am trying to check if the user puts any char other than letters and digits. But I am testing this regx ".*[^a-zA-Z0-9_].*" cause it was given to me by other developer

Comment: With the code example you give, there is no difference (assuming you have no further need for `match` outside of the code you provide). Without the `.*` will likely be imperceptively faster, but if you're worried about speed, then you can achieve the same thing without using regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.*[^a-zA-Z0-9_].*` will match the entire input as long as there is a non-alphanumeric/underscore somewhere in the input. `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]` will match only a single non-alphanumeric/underscore character (most likely the last one, if you're using the default greedy matching) if it is somewhere in the input. Which one you want depends on the input and what you want to do once you find out if a non-alphanumeric/underscore character exists in the input.

Comment: can you give me an example where it matches .*[^a-zA-Z0-9_].* but does not match [^a-zA-Z0-9_]

Comment: No. I can only give you an example where the matched portion is different. The input will either contain a portion that matches both expressions or neither of them.

Comment: so the output of both of them is the same ?

Comment: For the code that you provide, it is the same. If you were to check some other properties of your `match` variable, though (such as `Value`), you'll start to see a difference.

Answer (score 2):

The only difference would be whether the "margin characters" will be included in the result or not.

For:

`ab41--_71j`

It will match:

`1--_7`

And without the `.*` at beginning and end it will match:

`--_`

Any string will match the `.*[^a-zA-Z0-9_].*` regex at least once as long as it has at least one character that isn't a-zA-Z0-9_

From your currently last comment in your answer, I understand that you actually use:

`^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$`

This will match only if all characters are digit/letters.
If it doesn't match, then the string is invalid.

If you also want to allow the `_` character, then use:

`^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$`

Which can even be shortened to:

`^\w$`

In general, it is better to make regex's Validate rather than Invalidate strings. It just makes more sense and is more intuitive.

So my validation would look like:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch("anytest#", "^\\w$"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Success");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error");
}
```

Another option that is probably faster:

```
if ("anytest#".ToCharArray().All(c => char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || c == '_'))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Success");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error");
}
```

And if you don't want '_' to be included, it can even look nicer;

```
if ("anytest#".ToCharArray().All(char.IsLetterOrDigit))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Success");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error");
}
```

Comment: i need to make sure that "[^a-z A-Z0-9_]" and ".*[^a-z A-Z0-9_].*" gives the same output.
also --_ matches both of them

Comment: They don't always. They will only give the same output if the first and last characters of the string both aren't a-z or A-Z or 0-9 or _ because if they are, they will appear in the latter but not in the former.

Comment: @imad See edit for suggestion on what you should use, in my opinion, to make sure that all characters are letters or digits.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Yorye, but I am trying to study this expression .*[^a-zA-Z0-9_].* , cause it was given to me by other developer

Comment: @imad For your purpose, it doesn't matter. The difference is only in the match's value: With the `.*` it will be the whole invalid string, but without it, it will only be the substring that made it invalid.

Comment: but i do not agree with you that the following code is faster "if ("anytest#".ToCharArray().All(c => char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || c == '_')) "
labda is always a performance killer, use stopwatch and check the performance of lambda

Comment: I agree that a simple loop would be faster, but the idea is gotten there. Even like that, it will be probably faster than regex.

Answer (score 1):

No, because there are other characters than `a-Z` and `0-9`.

That regex matches all strings that start with **any** characters followed not by `a-zA-Z0-9` and end with **any** characters. Or just a string that does not contain  `a-zA-Z0-9` at all.

If you leave the `.*` then you just have a regex that matches a charatcer that does not contain  `a-zA-Z0-9` at all.

```
.*[^a-zA-Z0-9_].*  matches for instance: ABC_ß_ABC
[^a-zA-Z0-9_]      matches for instance: ß   (and this regex just matches 1 character)
```

Comment: so how ".*[^a-zA-Z0-9_].*" is different than "[^a-zA-Z0-9_]" ? can you give me an example

Comment: actually "ABC_ß_ABC" and "ß" will match both as I tested it

Comment: they will both match the first regex but not the second. `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]` matches just a **single** character.

Comment: hmmm ... did you try the code I have in my question, did you use the same one to check ?

Answer (score 1):

Input 1 : `ABC_ß_ABC`

Input 2 : `ß`

Regex 1: `.*[^a-zA-Z0-9_].*`
Regex 2: `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Both the inputs match both the regex,

**For input 1**

Regex 1 matches 9 characters

Regex 2 matches only 1 character

Answer (score 1):

Only include those tokens in the Regex that you are actually looking for. In your case you didn't actually care whether there are any other characters before or after the excluding character class you specified. Adding `.*` before and after that doesn't change the success of the match, but makes matching more complicated. A Regex matches anywhere already, unless you specifically anchor it somehow, e.g. using `^` at the start.